# How to verify sorting option result contain right results using selenium, java?

Tags: java, sorting, selenium, automation

In my application I have a table which contain form name and it has a sorting button. I want to verify whatever result coming after clicking on that sorting button is in sorted format(form name can contain alphabet, numbers, space, -)

I've written code up-to getting text from form name but struggling for how to verify.

```
 boolean flag = false;
 List<WebElement> list = WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='paymentFormsTable']//tbody//tr"));
 int size = list.size();
 for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
 String a = WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='paymentFormsTable']//tbody//tr[" + i
                                                         + "]//td[starts-with(@id,'payment-forms-form-name')]"))
                                                 .getText();
```

This is result and I want to verify weather it is sorted

> ```
> (testing form
> us
> us test form
> token veni form edit
> text test form
> text test form
> testing veni form
> testing form
> tester form
> Test-Partnere197
> Test-Partnere193
> Test-Partnere181
> Test-Partnere180
> Test-Partnere167
> Test-Partnere164
> Test-Partnere159
> Test-Partnere156
> Test-Partnere134)
> ```

Comment: What do you see when you Sysout `String a`

Comment: testing form us us test form, token veni form edit, text test form, text test form, testing veni form, testing form, tester form ,Test-Partnere197, Test-Partnere193, Test-Partnere181, Test-Partnere180, Test-Partnere167, Test-Partnere164, Test-Partnere159, Test-Partnere156, Test-Partnere134)

Comment: So now you want to sort all these elements?

Comment: @Dev these all is sorted result but I want to verify that sorting result is rightly sorted.

Comment: Through Selenium the elements are printed out as they are found in the HTML DOM. Now, before printing if you want to sort the elements that is related to Java. Selenium have no relation to sorting of a list. But you will be comparing the sorted list again what/whom? What would be your point of reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a reference sorted string, in order to compare with the actual order of the string. We can create a separate array and keep this array sorted. Later we need to take each string from each array in a same order and compare with each other.

If all the string matches through the arrays, then the order the elements are shown in webpage are sorted.

```
 boolean flag = false;
 List<WebElement> list = WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='paymentFormsTable']//tbody//tr"));
 int size = list.size();
 String[] actual = new String[size]; 
 String[] sorted = new String[size];

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
 {
    actual[i]=sorted[i] = WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='paymentFormsTabl']//tbody//tr[" + i+ "]//td[starts-with(@id,'payment-forms-form-name')]")).getText();
 }

 //Sorting the array
 Arrays.sort(sorted);

 //Validating the existing with sorted array. shows no message if both are same
 for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
 {
     if(!actual[i].equals(sorted[i]))
     {
         System.out.println("The elements the webpage are not sorted");
         System.out.println("expected "+sorted[i]+" but actual "+actual[i]+" at row "+i);
         flag = true;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My first element's index was 1 so I have changed little bit the previous answer. 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)

```
{
    int j=i+1;
    actual[i]=sorted[i] = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="view-clients-list-page--clients--table"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[' + j+ ']/td[1]')).getText();
     println(actual[i])
}
```

Comment: Arrays.sort(sorted, Collections.reverseOrder());